# how do I get bytecode hash of a smart contract?

Tags: ethers.js, zksync

Below is a snippet of code I am using to compute the hashed bytecode of a contract, however this doesn't seem to work. This hash is passed to the `create` function of the [zkSync Era ContractDeployer.sol system contract](https://github.com/matter-labs/v2-testnet-contracts/blob/b8449bf9c819098cc8bfee0549ff5094456be51d/l2/system-contracts/interfaces/IContractDeployer.sol#L68)?

```js
const contractDeployerAddress = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000008006"
const contractDeployer = new ethers.Contract(contractDeployerAddress, abi.abi, signer);

const salt = ethers.constants.HashZero;
const bytecodeUint8Array = utils.hashBytecode(guardianStorageArtifact.deployedBytecode)
console.log(bytecodeUint8Array)
const bytecodeHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(bytecodeUint8Array)
console.log(bytecodeHash)

const createCall = await contractDeployer.create(salt, bytecodeHash, "0x", {
gasLimit: 200000
});
const receipt = await createCall.wait();
console.log('Transaction confirmed in block:', receipt.blockNumber);
```

Comment: Instead of using `deployedBytecode` on the artifact have you tried using the `bytecode` field instead i.e. `guardianStorageArtifact.bytecode`? Also have you tried using the [hardhat-zksync-deploy plugin](https://era.zksync.io/docs/tools/hardhat/hardhat-zksync-deploy.html#setup) which provides a simple interface for deploying contracts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const contractDeployerAddress = "your address";
const contractDeployer = new ethers.Contract(contractDeployerAddress, abi.abi, signer);

const bytecode = guardianStorageArtifact.deployedBytecode;

const bytecodeHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(bytecode);

console.log('Bytecode Hash:', bytecodeHash);

const salt = ethers.utils.randomBytes(32); 

const createCall = await contractDeployer.create(salt, bytecodeHash, "0x", {
  gasLimit: 200000
});

const receipt = await createCall.wait();
console.log('Transaction confirmed in block:', receipt.blockNumber);
```